# Scraping Metacritic with urllib to follow redirect

Tags: python, web-scraping, screen-scraping, urllib

I'm working on a Python script to scrape information from Metacritic. It works fine for most movies but it has issues with movies that Metacritic redirects.

For example on the list of movies, Metacritic provides the url "/movie/red-riding-in-the-year-of-our-lord-1983" but when you click that URL it brings you to "/movie/red-riding-trilogy". I need urllib to fetch the HTML of the final URL it ends up at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the requests module. (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) Here is the code for the request and the line to save the final url.

```
response = requests.get(url)
newUrl = response.url
```

Comment: I will as soon I'm soon as I'm allowed to. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using,

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.FancyURLopener().open_http("your url")
```

Comment: I'm getting AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'request' on that line

Comment: @connor See my edit for the `import` statement that you're missing.

Comment: "ImportError: No module named request" I'm on python 2.7 so it may not have that module